# How to use common cs files to transfer variables between forms

Tags: c#

I am currently learning basics of c# window forms in visual studios and wondered how I use common cs files. I want to transfer variables from one file to another and I believe an easy way to do this is with a common cs file that just stores the variable and then i just reference it from each of the forms. So my questions are. How do i lay out the code for this common cs file ? if i reference the value in one form and then reference it in the next will it display the value recorded in the previous form or restart from 0. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. I would remove the basic tag from this post, as that is a different language altogether and might elicit some weird responses.

Your question seems to confuse the cs file with objects and references. So first up, there is nothing magical about a .cs file. It is just a file where c# code is. Often there is a 1-class-per-file convention, but this is just a developer aid, not a requirement. Your data itself will be in an object instance, and that object instance is defined by a class (that happens to be in a cs file).

A simple class definition might look like this

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then your first form can create an instance of a person like this:

```
    Person bob = new Person();
    bob.Id = 1;
    bob.Name = "Bob Dylan";
```

(or perhaps you would be assigning values from a control)

You then need to pass your person object instance to your other form. There are several ways that can be done and without understanding your problem domain, I cannot make judgement on which would be most appropriate. But if your second form had a public Person property, you could do something as simple as

```
Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
secondForm.Person = bob;
secondForm.Show();
```

or passing via constructor (if that is how it is defined)

```
Form2 secondform = new Form2(bob);
secondForm.Show();
```

Now your secondForm instance can access that bob object created above, either via the Person property, or within the constructor depending on how you wrote it.

Whilst this could also be done using static classes or even singletons, I think that until you are completely clear about regular classes, the use of these has the potential to lead you into various "code smells".

Comment: Thank you thats really useful. My only question is. can i create say 10 variables under one class called DatabseValues and then reference them across multiple forms?

Comment: also if i use the person bob = new person on multiple forms ( one to set the value and one to receive the variable to store it) would the value be reset on the second form when the person bob = new person is used or will it stay as the value set on the previous form?

Comment: Every call to new Person() creates a totally independent instance of a Person object. You can set yours to "Sally" and it won't change the one that I set to "Bob". If your second form has a field pointing to Bob, and you then ran the code `bob = new Person();`, then your field in that second form now references a different person instance. It does not change what is referenced on the first form.

Comment: So my issue is i need to store a variable from my first form into a textbox on my second form. I was told that the best way to do this was through a common cs file by my lecturer (Im new to this). What would you suggest?

Comment: In your first form, doing `secondForm.Person = bob;` is assigning that object instance to your second form. They point to the same piece of memory. Your second form can simply fill the appropriate controls from this data.

Comment: So, create a a common cs file with a class name in my case DatabaseVariables. In this class name create all my necessary variables. in my case initials, keywords, poems, UserInputs and UserOutputs. I then on my first form create a DatabaseVariables variable = new Databse variables. Then set my initials, input output variables ect. On my second form i do Form1.DataVariables inititals = maskedtextbox1.text?